# Find Bayes estimator of $\theta$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I've got this exercise, which I'm trying to work off using an example, but the example seems very different so I'm not sure if what I'm really doing.

> - I've got a loss distribution for $\theta$: $l(a,\theta)=\frac{(a-\theta)^2}{\theta(1-\theta)}$
> - I also know the the prior distribution $\pi(\theta)$ is Uniformly (continuous) distributed from 0 to 1.
> - The likelihood function is Bernoulli, X is the total number of ones in a sequence of n independent Bernoulli trials each with sample space {0,1} so $f(x|\theta) = \theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}$, $x=0,1$
>
> How do I find Bayes estimator of $\theta$?

So far, this is what I've tried:

$h(a,\theta)=E[l(a,\theta)]$

$h(a,\theta)=\int_0^1l(a, \theta)\pi(\theta|x)d\theta$

$h(a,\theta)=\int_0^1\frac{(a-\theta)^2}{\theta(1-\theta)}\frac{\Gamma{(3)}}{\Gamma{(x+1)}\Gamma{(2-x)}}{\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}}d\theta$

$h(a,\theta)=\frac{\Gamma{(3)}}{\Gamma{(x+1)}\Gamma{(2-x)}}\int_0^1(a-\theta)^2{\theta^{x-1}(1-\theta)^{-x}}d\theta$

I'm not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 3):

A hint: You want to minimize
$$
E[l(a, \theta)]=\int_0^1l(a, \theta)\pi(\theta|x)d\theta.
$$

Edit:

In the problem statement you say that *each* is Bernoulli. I assume this means that each trial is Bernoulli and that we have $n$ such trials. I also let $y=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ be the sum of these.

So, the derivative is proportional to (since we set it to 0, it doesn't matter)

$$
\frac{d}{da}\int (a-\theta)^2\theta^{y-1}(1-\theta)^{n-y-1}d\theta=2\int(a-\theta)\theta^{y-1}(1-\theta)^{n-y-1}d\theta=0
$$
and moving things around we get
$$
a\int\theta^{y-1}(1-\theta)^{n-y-1}d\theta=\int\theta^{y}(1-\theta)^{n-y-1}d\theta
$$
where the integrals resemble Beta densities, so we manipulate them to get
$$
a\frac{\Gamma(y)\Gamma(n-y)}{\Gamma(n)}\int\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(y)\Gamma(n-y)}\theta^{y-1}(1-\theta)^{n-y-1}d\theta=\frac{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(n-y)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\int\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(n-y)}\theta^{y}(1-\theta)^{n-y-1}d\theta\\
a=\frac{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(n-y)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(y)\Gamma(n-y)}=\frac{y}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
$$

With your loss function, this is the Bayes estimator.

Comment: Thanks
This is what I've got to but I'm not sure where to go from here:

$h(a,\theta)=E[l(a,\theta)]$


$=\int_0^1l(a, \theta)\pi(\theta|x)d\theta$

$=\int_0^1\frac{(a-\theta)^2}{\theta(1-\theta)}\frac{\Gamma{(3)}}{\Gamma{(x+1)}\Gamma{(2-x)}}{\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}}d\theta$

$=\frac{\Gamma{(3)}}{\Gamma{(x+1)}\Gamma{(2-x)}}\int_0^1(a-\theta)^2{\theta^{x-1}(1-\theta)^{-x}}d\theta$

Comment: @Jim Remember that you want to minimize this. Thus, you can differentiate and set the derivative to 0.

Comment: Ok? So take the derivative wrt to theta?
So does that just cancel out the integral? 
So that would give $a-\theta=0$, hence $a=\theta$??? I'm really not understanding...

Comment: @Jim Almost, do it with respect to $a$ instead.

Comment: But does that derivative then cancel out the integral?

Comment: @Jim No, it does not, because the integral is with respect to $\theta$. Have a look at the last page here: http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/466/hmwk6_sol.pdf It's not your problem, but the procedure is the same.

Comment: What exactly is going on in that line when they are differentiating? how are the 'thetas' turning into 'a' in the non integral part

Comment: @Jim It's because $\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx=\frac{d}{da}F(a)-\frac{d}{da}F(-\infty)=f(a)$.

Comment: But my integral is from 0 to 1, so $\frac{d}{da}F(1) - \frac{d}{da}F(0)$ = 0? I really don't know what to do, please help!!!

Comment: @Jim That's because the cases are a bit different. I would recommend you to find the posterior distribution, multiply it together with the loss function and write out the entire integrand. Then differentiate it wrt to $a$. That is, differentiate the last line in the original post.

Comment: That is the posterior distribution in the workings in the original post. I've pretty done what you have said, and I just don't know how to differentiate, if you could just show me how to do the next few steps that would be really helpful

Comment: @Jim See my updated post!

Comment: Thank you for that, so is my posterior that I previously derived correct: $\frac{\Gamma{(3)}}{\Gamma{(x+1)}\Gamma{(2-x)}}{\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}}$?

Comment: @Jim Yes, if you have only one trial. Note that the first part simplifies to 2 though. The terms in the denominator are 1 (if $x$ is 0 or 1) and the numerator is 2.

Comment: The question says 'X is the total number of ones in a sequence of n independent Bernoulli trials' - so I guess it's not 1 trial?

Comment: @Jim Then $X\sim Bin(n, \theta)$. This is what I used (but $y$ instead). So the posterior density that you used should be different.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure how to get the posterior otherwise. I've just been taught posterior = (likelihood * prior)/marginal

So marginal f(x)= integral of $\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}$ from 0 to 1 which gives 1/2

Then just subbing in the marginal and prior given in the question, along with the calculated marginal, gives me the posterior above.

Comment: @Jim The issue here is that $f(x|\theta)=f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n|\theta)=f(x_1|\theta)f(x_2|\theta)\cdots f(x_n|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i|\theta)$ because you have multiple (independent) trials. So the likelihood you used is for one single trial, i.e. $f(x_1|\theta)\neq f(x|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i|\theta)$. So you only used the likelihood for one trial when you need it for all of them (hence the product).

Comment: Thank you, I have the correct posterior now. Questions: With the differentiation, how did you get the 4 in front of the integral? And, does $\frac{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(n+1-y)}{\Gamma(n+2)}$ simplify to anything?

Comment: @Jim Oops, that shouldn't be there. Should be 2 (which comes from the exponent of $(a-\theta)^2$. And no, I don't think it does.